# IntelliSense finished initializing, but an error occurred while trying to load the document., Timed out while connecting to named pipe

Tags: visual-studio-2019

So recently, i have reinstalled windows, and now i have windows 10, i did some optimization, and installed some of my games, and apps, then i installed Visual Studio Community 2019, then i decided to create a new game, since i was bored, but when i tried to load the Designer file (Form1.vb [Designer]) it said IntelliSense finished initializing, but an error occurred while trying to load the document, and with the error code: 0x80131500, i tried disabling fast preview, and i tried relaunching, no luck. I haven't found other solutions. And i put my projects in Desktop\My Docs\Visual Studio Projects\Visual Basic\GameTest (Name of the game)

What do i do?

Comment: I have waited a bit like 4 months and for some reason it works a few weeks ago when I installed it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought the only way was to reset my PC and reinstall visual studio, but then I thought of resetting visual studio and it helped.
The error is basically due to some errors in importing the files. So I tried to reset the vs settings by simply going over to

**tools>import and export settings>reset all setings>general**

and hit next.

Answer (score 1):

i just logged out from my account and it works for me

Comment: Finally!  After hours of searching and trying various various suggestions, this is the one that eliminated the "Timed out while connecting to named pipe" error and I can open my form in the designer again!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When creating the new project as the .NET framework , you have to select the .NET Core 5 as the targeted framework. Do Not choose .NET Core 3.1 (Long Term Used).
Hope this gonna work For you!

Answer (score 0):

simply close the designer tab and press shift+f7
it will load refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Open your visual studio ----> open your project ------> go to your solution explorer and double click on your prject ---> change Target framework To (net472)-----> again go to your solution explorer and click right on your project and click on properties and change target framework to 4.7.2
Restart visual studio
That will successfully and work with me and will work with you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).